# How to turn on PhotoSwipe without click?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, photoswipe

I use the the mobile [PhotoSwipe](http://www.photoswipe.com/) gallery. My problem is that I need to load it not by click on image, but on clicks on the others elements on the page. May be there is some suggestions on ti?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the "click" function on any element as long as you code a link properly around the element with `rel="external"`, and as long as the link is contained inside of an element with the `gallery` class. If you have questions, I can post some example code.

Answer (score 0):

initialize photoswipe with:

```
photoswipe = $('.gallery a').photoSwipe()

$('#element').click(function (){
    photoswipe.show(1)
});
```

Index inside show are ipmortant, but you can use your value.

Answer (score -1):

well you can do something like this... if using jQuery...

```
$('#other_element').click(function (){
  $('#target').trigger('click');
});
```

I must admit, not much experience with PhotoSwipe, or the mobile version, but on normal jquery this is what you would of done.. I can't imagine it would be much different ... hope it helps...

Comment: what if click on #target used for other functionality?